# Assign Gridview DropDownList Value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I need the DropDownList ddlReceipt to display the value in the database. my current code is below.

I have a feeling that my code is wrong on ddlReceipt.SelectedValue = "toa_receipt"; but I am not for sure.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCreditCards.Rows)
{
    DropDownList ddlReceipt = row.FindControl("ddlReceipt") as DropDownList;
    string id = row.Cells[0].Text;
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(conStringTOA);
    SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT toa_receipt FROM toa_CreditCardStatement WHERE id = '" + id + "'");
    cmd2.Connection = con2;
    con2.Open();
    ddlReceipt.SelectedValue = "toa_receipt";
    con2.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a good part of code. You have to read data from DB (this is why you create `SqlCommand`).

```
//your code
//SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();//no need
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT toa_receipt FROM toa_CreditCardStatement WHERE id = @id", con2);
//It is very insecure to concatenate value into SQL string
//cmd2.Connection = con2;
//Use parameter instead
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id",DbType.VarChar).Value = id;
con2.Open();
using(SqlDataReader r = cmd2.ExecuteReader()){
   if(r.Read()){
      ddlReceipt.SelectedValue = (string)r["toa_receipt"];
   }
r.Close();
}
con2.Close();
```